# Using Clone() and setting external Id

Tags: apex, externalid, clone

I'm trying to clone a Case and modify a lookup using an external ID before inserting.

The problem is that I have this error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD, Cannot >specify both an external ID reference SubReason__r and a salesforce id, SubReason__c

here is my code

```
String unikkey = [SELECT UniqueKey__c FROM CaseQualification__c WHERE UniqueKey__c =: CASEQUALIF_COPYCONTRACRTSIGNED LIMIT 1].UniqueKey__c;
            for(Case_Request_Return_Contract__mdt caseRequestMdt : [SELECT Unique_Key__c FROM Case_Request_Return_Contract__mdt]){
                if(caseRequestMdt.Unique_Key__c == c.TechSubReasonUniqueKey__c){
                    CaseQualification__c cq = new CaseQualification__c(UniqueKey__c = unikkey);
                    Case clonedCase = CaseCloneService.cloneCase(c);
                    clonedCase.ParentId = c.Id;
                    clonedCase.SubReason__c = null;
                    clonedCase.SubReason__r = cq;
                    listClonedCase.add(clonedCase);
                }
            }
            insert listClonedCase;
```

EDIT: the case clone service is just a standard `clone(false,true,false,false)`. I can't specify `SubReason__c`  to not be set, Can I?.

As you see in the code I want to have my lookup `SubReason__c` be set to an external id, that is why I use `SubReason__r`.
The problem is even if I'm setting `subReason__c` to null I still have the error above.

Went to check this post: [Error Message When Using Clone Method in External ID scenario](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286501/error-message-when-using-clone-method-in-external-id-scenario)

And the guy have the same issue, resolved using maps which I could use but it would be more code and I would like to understand why it is not working when using clone.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure your "case clone service" can be told to not include the `SubReason__c`  field when querying the original Case and creating the clone.

Comment: Thanks Phil, i'm updating my post to explain what is in the clone service which is a basic apex Clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can't specify both the `__c` and `__r`, even if one of those are null. You'll need to change your method to not set the `SubReason__c` field at all, not even a null value, or query the `SubReason__c` values and use the ID.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of destroy the purpose of my clone method, which is a standard clone. 
Thanks for the answer tho. I'll just use maps instead.